# Multiple questions about initializing an array by **array or array[x][y]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have multiple questions regarding the two methods below to initialize a 2D array.

```
double *ptr, **y;
y = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double) * 5 * n); //initialize 2d array, allocate heap memory

ptr = (double *)(y + n); //ptr to point to the first element of 2D array

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) //loop to point rows pointer to appropriate location in 2D array
    y[i] = (ptr + 4 * i);
```

or

```
double y[n][4];
```

As far as I understand it atm, the first method is universal for all compilers, the second one isn't.

1. Why do I need to allocate memory for one column more in the first method? When I allocate memory for only 4 columns, it crashes.
2. Does the second method use heap memory? As far as I'm concerned I don't need the `free()` function for the second one.
3. Are there any more differences I'm not aware of?

Comment: Since the C99 standard (now over 20 years ago) the C language have supported [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Even so, neither `ptr` nor `y` from the first example are really the same as the array `y` from the second.

Comment: As for the second question, an array is an array. It doesn't matter what the contents of that array is (simple `int` values, structures, or other arrays), it's never allocated on the heap.

Comment: When I use `y` in following code, I can swap both methods and accessing values of the array works the same.

As far as I understand it now, both methods will give me pointers to point to the memory locations of the arrays. (probably wrong, please correct me)

So first difference is that the second `y` is in stack and not in heap, right?

Comment: The next thing you need to learn is that an array is ***not*** the same as a pointer. An array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element (e.g. with `double a[10];` then `a` on its own decays to `&a[0]`).

Comment: As for helping you understand the difference, I suggest you use pen and paper to draw everything. For pointers, use arrows for the pointers themselves. For array or memory allocated by `malloc` use rectangles subdivided into smaller squares for each element. Label the elements, and draw arrows for pointers to them.

Comment: [that](https://imgur.com/qr7XtTS) would be how I understand it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we create an example with small sizes, lets say a 2 by 3 matrix, then using the first method would create something like this:

```
+-----+
| ptr | ------\
+-----+       |
              v
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| y[0] | y[1] | y[0][0] | y[0][1] | y[0][2] | y[1][0] | y[1][1] | y[1][2] |
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
   |      |   ^                             ^
   |      |   |                             |
   \------|---/                             |
          |                                 |
          \---------------------------------/
```

In the second example you don't have any pointers at all, and it looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| y[0][0] | y[0][1] | y[0][2] | y[1][0] | y[1][1] | y[1][2] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

And a very big and important note: The first method only works if `sizeof(double) >= sizeof(double *)`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So I actually should use this for malloc, because I need to free memory for a row of pointers that point to the beginning of each row: `y = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * n + sizeof(double) * 4 * n);`

Comment: What is the difference between the two at machine code level apart from heap/stack? Is there any advantage of one compared to the other except for smaller code? Why would I want to use the pointers?